# Android XML Layout Issues

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, samsung-mobile

The cover art doesn't scale and the arrow placement/size in the header is also wrong.

This is my xml for the cover art: https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/23db5012b65e53f4a37a

What are some best practices to supporting different screen sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML says to center the image inside the view bounds. Your cover art is too low resolution to fill the space that you expect it to. You should either provide larger art for higher densities, or set the ImageView to a specific height and set the scale type to fitCenter.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Let me try that.

Comment: If I do fitCenter the image just blows up without me even changing the height.

Comment: Correct. You can do that, but you may want to limit how large it gets.  A low res image isn't going to look good on larger screens.

Comment: How would i limit it? THe height is set to 0dp and when i change the width then the image is no longer centered.

Comment: You could have different layouts for different size screens. If you just want to keep it centered, you just need to set the view's layout_gravity to center.

Comment: Sweet. Worked perfectly. layout_gravity was just the missing piece I needed. What are your thoughts on the arrow between MOOD & CALM?